# Delete entry from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries..

```
self.books = {}
newbook = {'Quantity': '1', 'Price': '1.58',   'Id': '1006', 'Title': 'Book1', 'Status': 'Out'}
```

I add orders like so:

```
self.books[newbook['Price']] = newbook
```

To show all the book entries:

```
for books in self.books.values():
    print("{0}".format(order))

{'Quantity': '3', 'Price': '7.56',   'Id': '1003', 'Title': 'To kill a  mock', 'Status':'In'}
{'Quantity': '7', 'Price': '2.9',   'Id': '1002', 'Title': 'LOTR', 'Status':'In'}
{'Quantity': '2', 'Price': '5.45',   'Id': '1001', 'Title': 'HPATFS', 'Status':'Out'}
{'Quantity': '12', 'Price': '11.57',   'Id': '1004', 'Title': 'Best book ever', 'Status':'Out'}
```

Unfortunately I can't delete a book entry based on Id or Price or Status? I've tried del or pop, but the entry still remains.

```
for k, v in self.books.items():
    if k == books['Id']:
    # del self.books[k]
    self.books.pop(books['Id'], None)
```

Comment: You are keying your dictionaries by *price*: `self.book[newbook['Price']] = ..`. You'd have to use the same key again. Your `k` will *never* be equal to the `neworder['OrderId']`, because your keys are prices, not order ids.

Comment: Hold on... You use the Price as key? What if there are two books with the same price? Then you can hold only one book?

Comment: Why not use the `'Id'` value as a key? Then you can just do `self.orderbook.pop(neworder['OrderId'], None)` *without looping*.

Comment: Its a swap shop implementation. If two books are the same price or close to the same price then you can swap the books. So I want to list and sort by price. But additional functionality specifies that you can remove a book after adding it.. So if I add a book a 1.99, then decide I want to remove it, I don't want to remove all books that were 1.99.

Comment: Unless, could I create the dicts with a key of 'Id' but then could I search books for a price and if two prices match perform a swap based on the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you can't use values that you are not sure are unique as keys for a dictionary. Dictionaries are indexed by their key and indexing has to be unique. In fact, the language doesn't even allow you to try to add two entries with the same value. Adding the second item simply overwrites the first:

```
>>> d = {'a':1}
>>> d.update({'a':2})
>>> print(d)
{'a': 2}
```

So, you definitely should use the `'Id'` value as the key for your dictionary, assuming your Ids are in fact unique.

Because of this, the rest of your question boils down to finding a dictionary entry by it's value instead of it's key. For this, you have to define a behavior for when the dict contains multiple entries with that value. I'm going to assume you want a list of all Ids with the specified pricetag.

The only way I can think of for this that accounts for the possibility of multiple entries with the same value is simply iterating over dict:

```
def findKeysByValue(dic, value):
  match_keys = []
  for key, val in dic.items():
    if val == value:
      match_keys.append(key)
  return match_keys
```

(use `dic.iteritems()` instead for Python 2.X)

Which yields for example:

```
>>> d = {'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3, 'k4':2, 'k5':2}
>>> findKeysByValue(d,2)
['k5', 'k2', 'k4']
```

Once you know the key of the book that interests you, you can apply all dictionary operations on that key.

There are two different problems with the last part of your code. Firstly, `pop` takes a key from your dictionary as an argument, not a value. Also, this code produces a `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, because you iterate over the dictionary itself and remove an item every cycle. You can circumvent this by iterating over a copy of your dict, i.e.:

```
copy_dict = self.books.copy()
for k in copy_dict:
  if k == books['Id']:
    self.books.pop(k, None)
```

Depending on the size of `self.books` though, this may not be suitable, because you have double the space requirement.

Comment: Ok, if I change it so I have a key of Id, then I can delete by that id. But I get an error "dictionary changed size during iteration".

Comment: I edited my answer to adress the last part of your question.

Comment: Thanks. The amended copy of dict works like a charm.